# Adding multiple scopes in BasicNameValuePair

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to add multiple scopes instead of scope ("aaaaaa") in below code

```java
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", "aaaaa"));
```

The scope looks like this (with space between them): **scope="aaaaa bbbbb"**

The curl looks like

```js
cURL ..."grant_type=authorization_code&&scope=aaaaa bbbbb"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is putting addition sign (+) between the scopes

```java
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", "aaaaa+bbbbb"));
```